# How can I pull and Push two div on a same column aligning vertically in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can pull and push 2 columns when they are on right and left but I am not able to order the column when the 2 columns are vertically align.

What I want to do is on big screen I want to column 1 (product details text) to appear first and on smaller screen I want column 2 (thumbnail part) to appear before column 1, Such that on smaller screen it appears after the big image of the slider

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> 
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1>Products</h1>  
        <h3>Some product subhead</h3>
        <p>Product description goes here.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
        <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</p>


    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="clearfix col-sm-6">
              <div class="carousel-link">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
  </div> <!-- /row -->
  </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS

```
.carousel-link .thumb {
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.carousel-link .thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}
.carousel-link .thumb:first-of-type img {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.carousel-link .thumb:last-of-type img {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/k5L37/1/)**

You can club the carousel and its links (thumbnails) in one.

css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="carousel-link">
                            <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main">
                            </div>
                            <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2">
                            </div>
                            <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3">
                            </div>
                            <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <h1>Products</h1> 
                 <h3>Some product subhead</h3>

                <p>Product description goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
                <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /row -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Thank for your try. But this is not what I am looking for because I want the thumbnails to appear after the details text on big screen and want the thumbnail to appear before the details text only on smaller screen. Thanks